# como hago un filtrador de registros (un buscador de peliculas por palabra)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, filtro, buscador

como hago un filtrador de registros (un buscador de peliculas)?

Estoy creando mi propio emprendimiento en peliculas online, y necesito un buscador que me filtre las peliculas por nombre, ¿¿como lo hago??, me podrian ayudar por favor.

les dejo mi codigo

como hago un filtrador de registros (un buscador de peliculas)?

Estoy creando mi propio emprendimiento en peliculas online, y necesito un buscador que me filtre las peliculas por nombre, ¿¿como lo hago??, me podrian ayudar por favor.

les dejo mi codigo

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Netflix 1.1</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../package/css/swiper.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.scss">

  <!-- Demo styles -->
  <style>

  </style>
</head>
<body>


  <div class="flip">
    <a href="https://dribbble.com/shots/2507318-start-rollover" target="_blank">
        <div class="front">Reproducir</div>
        <div class="back">Ver</div>
    </a>
  </div>


<div class="imagen-principal">
  <img id="principal" width="55%" src="imgprincipal/1.jpg" alt="">
 <h3>GRETEL & HANSEL</h3>
<h4>La protagonista, una niña llamada Gretel, vive inmersa en un mundo peligroso. Cuando no logra conseguir trabajo de sirvienta, lleva a su hermano pequeño Hansel a un bosque oscuro en una búsqueda desesperada de comida y trabajo, solo para tropezar con el malvado plan de Holda, una bruja.</h4>
</div>


  <!-- Swiper -->


  <div class="netflix-slider">
    <h2>Popular on Netflix</h2>
    <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Movie Title"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Movie Title"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/3.jpg" alt="Movie Title"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/4.jpg" alt="Movie Title"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/5.jpg" alt="Movie Title"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/6.jpg" alt="Movie Title"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/7.jpg" alt="Movie Title"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/8.jpg" alt="Movie Title"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/9.jpg" alt="Movie Title"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/10.jpg" alt="Movie Title"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- Add Pagination -->
      <!-- <div class="swiper-pagination"></div> -->
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="netflix-slider">
    <h2>Continue watching...</h2>
    <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Movie Title"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Movie Title"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/3.jpg" alt="Movie Title"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/4.jpg" alt="Movie Title"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/5.jpg" alt="Movie Title"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/6.jpg" alt="Movie Title"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/7.jpg" alt="Movie Title"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/8.jpg" alt="Movie Title"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/9.jpg" alt="Movie Title"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/10.jpg" alt="Movie Title"></div>
      </div>





      <!-- Add Pagination -->
      <!-- <div class="swiper-pagination"></div> -->
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>
  </div>




<!--- FILTRADO DE BUSQUEDA -->






  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="../package/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      slidesPerView: 6,
      spaceBetween: 10,
      slidesPerGroup: 2,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
    });
  </script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
let movies = [
  {title : "Inception", imageUrl: "add image url"},
  {title : "Sons of Anarchy", imageUrl: "add image url"}
];

function myFunction() {
  let result = "";
  movies.forEach(function (item) {
    result += "<div class='swiper-slide'><img src='"+ item.imageUrl +"' alt='alt text'> " + item.title + " ";
  });

  document.getElementById("listMovies").innerHTML = result;
}

myFunction();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si sólo vas a cargar las películas a mano en esa variable `movies` y queres filtrarlas es muy fácil con [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) y para comparar lo que pongas en tu input de búsqueda contra el nombre de la película podes usar [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) con [expresiones regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Sería algo así:

```js
const movies = [{
    title: "Inception",
    imageUrl: "add image url"
  },
  {
    title: "Sons of Anarchy",
    imageUrl: "add image url"
  }
];
const search = /Incep/g;
const result = movies.filter(movie => movie.title.match(search));
console.log(result)
// [{ title: "Inception", imageUrl: "add image url"}]
```

Comment: si las voy a cargar a mano, si podrias dejarme el codigo te agradeceria

Comment: ahí te deje un ejemplo, saludos